# Which version of Net-Snmp supports only snmp v1 and v2c but doesn't support v3?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I want to use a snmpd that only support snmp v1 and v2c but doesn't support v3, I read the history file of net-snmp but didn't find any clue that from which version the net-snmp begin to support snmp v3.
anyone can help? thanks in advance!

Comment: You can compile your own fork and remove v3 related code. Don't go to an old release as that could be too old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The net-snmp changelog](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/about/ChangeLog.html) highlights in v4.0:

```
  New:
    - SNMPv3 protocol support!!!
      (See the README.snmpv3, snmpusm(1), snmp.conf(5), snmpd.conf(5))
```

The previous release was 3.6.2.

The [release schedule](http://www.net-snmp.org/dev/schedule.html) notes that the final release in the 4.2 series was in 2008 and that it, as well as anything prior, is unsupported.